# Helicity of cosmic neutrinos

Tags: neutrinos, helicity

If neutrino has mass, then it can change it's helicity. But all registered neutrinos have negative helicity while all anti-neutrinos have positive.

Does it stands for all registered neutrinos including cosmic ones? I.e. does it mean that cosmic neutrinos had not enough time to switch their helicity? Or it was checked only for neutrinos in accelerator experiments, i.e. only for "young" neutrinos? What about solar neutrinos? Is their helicity known?